# how can we append two attributes by one function?

Tags: php, laravel, model, append

I want to add two appends variables in laravel model. by using one getVariableNameAttribute() function.

Is this possible?

MY motto is, I want to reduce SQL query load 2 times to into 1 time

```
class Like extends Model{
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = ['like_id', 'like_type', 'liked', 'user_id'];
protected $appends = ['likes','dislikes'];
protected function getLikesAttribute($type)
{
    return \DB::table("likes")
        ->select(\DB::raw("SUM(liked) as likes"))
        ->where('like_type',self::class)->where('like_id',$this->id)->first()->likes;
}
public function getDislikesAttribute()
{
    return \DB::table("likes")
        ->select(\DB::raw("SUM(!liked) as dislikes"))
        ->where('like_type',self::class)->where('like_id',$this->id)->first()->dislikes;
}}
```

Comment: I mean... you can make `getVariableNameAttribute()` return a combination of two attributes, or an array containing two attributes or an object containing two attributes. The amount of SQL queries depends on your implementation. It's not weird for Accessors to not even touch the database

Comment: it's possible, please show your current code first

Comment: I have added my code in my question description. Please check. @IGP I want to create a method getVariableNameAttribute() for two variables.  is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Combining both methods to return an object is possible.

```php
protected function getVariableNameAttribute()
{
    return \DB::table("likes")
        ->selectRaw("SUM(liked) as likes")
        ->selectRaw("SUM(!liked) as dislikes")
        ->where('like_type', self::class)
        ->where('like_id', $this->id)
        ->first();
}
```

- `$...->variable_name->likes`
- `$...->variable_name->dislikes`

Comment: yes, it can be work, Thank you for your answer. but I need to do separate two variables.